# Update XML data for multiple nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I want to update the Isselected plan data based on the selected plan

```
            SET @DataXml.modify(' replace value of (/*/Plans/Plan[sql:variable("@PlanID")]/Details/IsSelected/text())[1] with sql:variable("IsSelectedValue")')
```

but the above query always update the first one.

```
<Plans>
        <Plan>
          <Details>
               <IsSelected>true</IsSelected>
         </Details>  
        </plan> 
        <Plan>
          <Details>
                 <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
         </Details>  
        </plan> 
        <Plan>
          <Details>
                <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
         </Details>  
        </plan>
  </Plans>


if((SELECT count(Col.value('(Details)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')) AS Selected FROM @DataXml.nodes('Options/Option') AS Tbl(Col)) > 1)
                                BEGIN                   

                                    SET @DataXml.modify(' replace value of (/*/Options/Option[sql:variable("@OptionID")]/Details/IsSelectedValue/text())[1] with sql:variable("@IsSelectedValue")')
                                END
                            ELSE
                            BEGIN                            

                                    SET @DataXml.modify(' replace value of (/*/Options/Option/Details/IsSelectedValue/text())[1] with sql:variable("@IsSelectedValue")')
                            END
```

if I can get the node count like say for the above data It should return count 3 I can manage to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is probably to late... But it might still be helpfull...

I must admit, that I did not understand your issue completely. Try this out:

A *mockup-XML*

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<Plans>
        <Plan>
          <Details>
               <IsSelected>true</IsSelected>
         </Details>  
        </Plan> 
        <Plan>
          <Details>
                 <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
         </Details>  
        </Plan> 
        <Plan>
          <Details>
                <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
         </Details>  
        </Plan>
  </Plans>';
```

--This query will answer your question

> if I can get the node count like say for the above data It should return count 3 I can manage to fix this

```
SELECT @xml.value('count(/Plans/Plan)','int') AS CountOfPlans;
```

--And this query will change the second `<IsSelected>` to a new value

```
DECLARE @position INT=2;
DECLARE @newValue VARCHAR(100)='blah';

SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/Plans/Plan[sql:variable("@position")]/Details/IsSelected/text())[1] with sql:variable("@newValue")');

SELECT @xml;
```

The first returns a "3" and the second this XML

```
<Plans>
  <Plan>
    <Details>
      <IsSelected>true</IsSelected>
    </Details>
  </Plan>
  <Plan>
    <Details>
      <IsSelected>blah</IsSelected>
    </Details>
  </Plan>
  <Plan>
    <Details>
      <IsSelected>false</IsSelected>
    </Details>
  </Plan>
</Plans>
```